# How to determine what ports X is listening on?

Tags: ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

My use case is that I am running nx over ssh and the local proxy connects to the remote host via tunneling. Because it's tunneled, I tell nx to connect to localhost:port. The problem is that I need to perform X authentication and if I hit the local X server by accident instead of the remote one, I get an authentication error.

How can I determine what port the local X server is listening on so that I can avoid it when setting up my tunnel?

My current workaround is to avoid tunneling with any local port which already has another application listening on it.

Comment: This would be a better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: what operating system are you talking about?

Comment: I'm hoping for a portable solution. But for simplicity, lets say it's CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 7):

It's usually screen number + 6000. For example, if `$DISPLAY` is `:5` port number is 6005

Comment: I still need to know which port it's actually on.

Comment: do you have access to server's `$DISPLAY` variable? If not, the only way is to try to connect incrementally starting from port 6000

Comment: Querying the display variable does not provide a solution if there are multiple servers running across multiple accounts.

Comment: then look at X process command line - `X :3` starts server with :3 DISPLAY

Comment: Is the port "6000" documented somewhere?

Comment: @yaobin https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=x11

Answer (score 2):

Querying the display variable does not provide a solution if there are multiple servers running across multiple accounts.